# Getting cardinality from ordinal encoding in Scikit-learn

Tags: encoding, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I'm using the `OrdinalEncoder` to encode categorical data in Scikit-learn and I'm looking for a way to get details about the encoding. I.e. the cardinality of each feature or even the exact mapping between the numbers and categories.

Short of the `inverse_transform` method I can't see a way of doing this. I want to do this as generally as possible, i.e. without knowing the categories in advance.

I'm aware of the issues with ordinal encoding (onehot is not an option for me). I've also looked at DictVectorizer but I am not sure whether it is appropriate.

Comment: I think you are mis-using the word cardinality here. cardinality means count of a particular object. May be give some examples, to explain what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I recreated the official documentation example,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)
```

Now, if you want to see the encoding, you simply call the `categories_` attribute, so in this case:

```
print(enc.categories_)
#Output: [array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)]
```

Now, this only returns the encoded features and not their encoding. However, their index itself is the encoding. For example, in this case, `Female` is encode to `0`, `Male` is encoded to `1`, then moving forward to the next set of features, `1` is encoded as `0`, `2` is encoded as `1` and so on.

So, if I want to get the encoding of `Female` and `Male`:

```
encoding = enc.categories_
encoding_sex = dict(zip((encoding[0]), range(len(encoding[0]))))
print(encoding_sex)
# Output: {'Female': 0, 'Male': 1}
```

Now if you want to generalize the above method for all features and make it fast as well, do the following :

```
encoding = enc.categories_
encoding_feature = lambda x: dict(zip(x, range(len(x))))
encoding_full = [encoding_feature(feature_elem) for feature_elem in encoding]
print(encoding_full)
# Output: [{'Female': 0, 'Male': 1}, {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thanks. It turns out the reason I'm having trouble is I'm using a column transformer to apply the encoding to only a few columns. I keep getting `'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute 'categories_'` when I query the attribute. Let me know if this belongs in a separate question.

Comment: @robtherobot101 yeah I think that would indeed require a seperate question with the code that you are using, along with the complete stack trace if possible, since I can't exactly tell the solution without seeing the code :-) I would be happy to help you with the new question. If you find this answer useful, can you please upvote and mark it as the correct one ?

Answer (score 1):

`categories_` does have the mapping, which is required for `inverse_transform`. You can have a look at the `inverse_transform` code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py#L960).

May be you are looking for a explicit dictionary between numbers and categories, then use

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
>>> enc = OrdinalEncoder()
>>> X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
>>> enc.fit(X)
... 
OrdinalEncoder(categories='auto', dtype=<... 'numpy.float64'>)

>>> [dict(enumerate(mapping)) for mapping in enc.categories_]
# [{0: 'Female', 1: 'Male'}, {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}]
```